# Using "if" with an adjective

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Here are the sentences I'm asking about:

> These promising, **if expensive**, travel innovations were soon curtailed by wartime conditions in Asia and Europe. *(Source: The Independent, https://bit.ly/3I243IM)*

> The accommodation is pleasant, **if basic**, and doubles cost from £65 including breakfast. *(Source: Encyclopedia Britannica, https://bit.ly/3C3F5Vx)*

In these contexts, does "if" mean "although"? If yes, is there a name for this grammatical rule?

Comment: Can you please clarify if the sentences are your own or copied from somewhere? If they are not your own, please edit your question and tell us the name of the site or the book. It will help users to know if the authors are native speakers or not. P.S In my view, the examples are written in perfectly good English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done. I found these sentences on Ludwig, but I tracked the actual sources and added them to the question.

Comment: The links go  vice-versa though-ops. Thanks for going into the trouble of finding the source, excellent!

Answer (score 1):

"if" doesn't exactly mean "although".

As mentioned on [Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/although), one synonym for although is "even if". I believe that "even if" could be used here.

Also, there are a few changes that can improve your sentence:

> These promising travel innovations, even if they were expensive, were soon curtailed by wartime conditions in Asia and Europe.
>
> Even if it looks basic, the accommodation is pleasant here, and doubles cost from £65 including breakfast.

---

I think "despite" and "in spite of" suits this context the best.

> These promising travel innovations, despite being expensive, were soon curtailed by wartime conditions in Asia and Europe.
>
> In spite of looking basic, the accommodation is pleasant here, and doubles cost from £65 including breakfast.

As mentioned on [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/insights/post/grammar-despite-in-spite-of/):

> Despite and in spite of both mean “without being affected by the particular factor mentioned.”

Which is what you're trying to describe.

---

Your sentence is grammatically correct, I am just suggesting alternative options.

Comment: Are you saying the examples cited by the OP are ungrammatical? I don't find anything wrong with them at all.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Edited my answer.

Comment: The answer still says *Also, there are a few changes required **to modify "your sentence"** (they are not the OP's creation, the authors are apparently British) **to be grammatical**. Please explain why you think the two examples are ungrammatical, and why "despite" or "in spite of" fits better? That's your opinion, but based on what?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Edited my answer.

Comment: [2. **even though**:
“an enthusiastic if small audience”.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/if) Source: Dictionary.com